# Bash escrever saída no terminal e em arquivo

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal

Estou criando um script e preciso que as saídas sejam mostradas no terminal, porém também salvas em um arquivo

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Olá Mundo"
```

e estou redirecionando a saída para o arquivo da seguinte maneira

```bsh
./teste.sh > saida.txt
```

assim a string `Ola mundo` é corretamente salva no arquivo.

Como faço para que além do arquivo ela também seja impressa na tela ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, você poderia fazer isso através do comando `tee` que faz o que tá na imagem abaixo, obtida deste [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tee-command-linux-example/):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Passa comando e ele salva no arquivo e joga no stdout, logo o código seria:

```
echo "Olá Mundo" | tee saida.txt
```

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta.

Comment: @ViviSantana obrigado,

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Estava tentando algo com `./test.sh > saida.txt 2>&0 2>&1` sem sucesso.